Gitlab GraphQL get all commits for a given user
I am trying to retrieve a complete list of actions performed by a user (events) in my self-hosted GitLab instance. Specifically, I need a list of:

Commits (e.g., commit hashes or identifiers)
Created/Closed issues.
Created/Merged/Closed merge requests.

And most important: timestamps of these actions!
I'm aware of the GitLab REST API /events endpoint, which allows me to get this kind of data. Here's an example of what I used:
https://<my_gitlab_instance>/api/v4/users/<id>/events

However, I've noticed that the REST API's events endpoint is limited to events from the last 3 years only. Unfortunately, I need to retrieve actions that go beyond this time limit.

Is there a way to use the newer GitLab GraphQL API to obtain the same kind of information without the 3-year limitation? (without Premium or Unlimited features)
If so, could you please provide some guidance or an example query that retrieves user actions (including commits and issues) with their corresponding timestamps?

Any help on how to achieve this with the GraphQL API, or any other approach to bypass the time limitation, would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
